# Intersection in DB2 using INTERSECT

Tags: java, db2, db2-luw, intersect

I have a query in DB2 that I need intersection on.

```
SELECT  * FROM records where id = 1
intersect 
SELECT  * FROM records where id = 2
```

Now this size of ids can grow dynamically, do we have anything in DB2 that can take the list of ids as the parameter? something like
`intersect in (1,2,3,4,5)` so that it may consider intersection on of result set on these ids using a single query?

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?

Comment: @data_henrik DB2 v 9.7.200

Comment: You can use a CTE for simple cases. Otherwise consider putting the list of IDs into a session table (indexing dynamically if justifiable), and intersect on that.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo The query you provided can't return non-empty result set - the `id` column has different values in all sub-sets, and you must exclude it from the `select` list. We do have an ability to convert a string like `1,2,3` to a list of integers. The solution would be to: join the `records` table to this list of integers, group by a list of intersected columns (you need to provide such a list, which doesn't include the `id` column) with `having count(distinct id) = "length_of_the_ids_list"` condition. I can provide an example, If this is what you really need.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a TABLE with the ID LIST, and then create a procedure to create dinamically the SQL Statement to Execute.

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
    YOUR_PROCEDURE
    (
    )
    LANGUAGE SQL
    SPECIFIC YOUR_PROCEDURE
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS
    SET OPTION
        ALWBLK = *ALLREAD ,
        ALWCPYDTA = *YES ,
        COMMIT = *NONE ,
        CLOSQLCSR = *ENDMOD ,
        DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) ,
        DFTRDBCOL = *NONE ,
        DLYPRP = *NO ,
        DYNDFTCOL = *NO ,
        DYNUSRPRF = *USER ,
        SRTSEQ = *HEX ,
        OUTPUT = *PRINT,
        DBGVIEW = *SOURCE
BEGIN
    DECLARE LAST_ELEMENT SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 ;
    DECLARE FIRST_ELEMENT SMALLINT DEFAULT 1 ;
    DECLARE STMT VARCHAR ( 5000 ) ;
    DECLARE ID_CODE_TO_USE NUMERIC (9 , 0) ;

    DECLARE ID_LIST CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        ID_CODE
    FROM
        YOUR_TEMPORARY_TABLE ;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET LAST_ELEMENT = -1 ;

    OPEN  ID_LIST ;
    SET STMT = '' ;
    SET FIRST_ELEMENT = 1 ;

    FETCH_ID_LIST:
    LOOP
        FETCH ID_LIST
        INTO
        ID_CODE_TO_USE ;

    -------
        IF LAST_ELEMENT = -1 THEN
            LEAVE FETCH_ID_LIST ;
        END IF ;
    -------
        IF FIRST_ELEMENT= 1 THEN
            SET STMT = 'SELECT  * FROM RECORD WHERE ID = ' CONCAT  CHAR(ID_CODE_TO_USE)
            SET FIRST_ELEMENT = 0 ;
        END IF ;

    -------
        SET STMT = 'INTERSECT SELECT  * FROM RECORD WHERE ID = ' CONCAT  CHAR(ID_CODE_TO_USE)
    END LOOP FETCH_ID_LIST;

    CLOSE  ID_LIST ;
    IF STMT <> '' THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STMT ;
    END IF ;
END ;
```

Comment: the system is in production, it's a turn around and would be hectic, I can create the quer dynamically using code. I just wanted to know if there is any thing that DB2 provides.

Comment: No, I think you must create SQL dinamically, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 0):

Run this as is:

```
with ids (id) as 
(
  select id
  from xmltable
  (
    'for $id in tokenize($s, ",") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' 
    -- the following string of IDs may be passed as a parameter
    passing '1,2,3' as "s"
    columns id int path 'if (. castable as xs:integer) then xs:integer(.) else ()'
  )
)
, tab (id, c1, c2) as 
(
  values
  (1, 1, 1)
, (1, 1, 1)
, (2, 1, 1)
, (2, 1, 1)
, (3, 1, 1)
, (1, 2, 2)
, (2, 2, 2)
)
select t.c1, t.c2 
from tab t
join ids i on i.id=t.id
group by t.c1, t.c2
having count(distinct t.id) = (select count(1) from ids);

C1 C2
-- --
 1  1
```

If this is not you want to have, then provide some example with source data and the exact result desired.